# poetry version patch not working on azure pipelines

Tags: python, azure-devops, python-poetry

I have the following azure devops pipilines

```
trigger:
- master


variables:
  # Primary virtual environment used for poetry.
  # Also made available to .ap/scripts/python.py to resolve to the correct
  #  Python.
  venv: .poetry
  app_venv: .venv

jobs:
- job: Pipeline
  strategy:
    matrix:
      linux:
        python.version: '3.10'
        imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
    maxParallel: 4

  pool:
    vmImage: $(imageName)

  steps:
    # Arbitrary cache key properties.
  - bash: |
      echo '
      python_version=$(python.version)
      os=$(Agent.OS)
      ' > buildinfo.txt
    displayName: 'Create CI properties file'

  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.10'
    displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
 
  - script: |
      python -m pip install -U pip
      pip install poetry
      poetry install
    displayName: Install dependencies

  - script: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$HOME/.poetry/bin"
    displayName: Add poetry to PATH
    
  - script: |
      poetry version patch
    displayName: 'Poetry Version patch'
    
  - script: |
      poetry_version=$(poetry version --no-ansi | awk '{print $2}')
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildVersion]$poetry_version"
    displayName: 'set build version'

  - script: |
      poetry build
    displayName: 'Poetry Build'

  - powershell: |
      $semver = "$(buildVersion)"
      $newRunName = "$semver"
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$newRunName"
    displayName: 'Update Run Name'
  
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
    inputs:
      artifactName: 'artifacts_$(buildVersion)_$(Agent.OS)'
      targetPath: dist/
    displayName: Publish artifacts
```

There are no errors, however the patch version is not increasing as it should it keeps building the same version.

So I did the following test:

1. Run poetry version patch locally, version its increased then I commit to devops.
2. Pipeline runs and patch number is changed, but now 2 numbers. So if it was 0.0.21 then it got increased to 0.0.23